# Producing a partially applied function from method of type in an Option

Tags: scala, partial-application, scala-option

Suppose I'm writing a GUI

[image]

```
class Kitteh (val age: Int) {
  require (age < 5)
  def saveMeow(file: File) = { /* implementation */ }
  def savePurr(file: File) = { /* implementation */ }
}
```

The frame has a field for the current Kitteh, which is an `Option` because it might not have been defined yet, or the user may have attempted to create an invalid one:

```
var currentKitteh: Option[Kitteh] = None
```

Now I want to create a `Kitteh` safely when the user hits Create

```
val a = ... // parse age from text box
currentKitteh = try { Some(new Kitteh(a)) } catch { case _ => None }
```

My GUI has two buttons which do similar things. In psedocode, they should both

```
if (currentKitteh.isDefined) {
  if (file on the disk already exists) {
    bring up a dialog box asking for confirmation
    if (user confirms)
       << execute method on currentKitteh >>
  }
}
else bring up warning dialog
```

Don't worry about the detail: the point is that because there is code duplication, I want to create a common method that I can call from both buttons. The only difference is the method on the Kitteh that needs to be executed.

Now if `currentKitteh` were not an `Option`, the common method could have a signature like

```
def save(filename: String, f:(File => Unit)) {
```

which I could call with, for example

```
save("meow.txt", currentKitteh.saveMeow _)
```

but since it is actually an Option, how could I implement this?

I could just check whether currentKitteh is defined, and do a `.get` before calling the `save` method for each button, but is there another way, leaving this check in the `save` method? In other words, given an `Option[A]`, is it possible to specify a partial function from a method on the (possibly non-existent) `A` object?

(hope this question makes sense, convoluted example notwithstanding)

**edit**: Bonus question: what if, instead of `Option[Kitteh]`, I used `Either[Throwable, Kitteh]`?

**update**: Additional line added to pseudocode to bring up warning dialog: ideally, the `save` method should always be called so that the user is warned if there is no valid Kitteh to save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the best option to me:

```
currentKitteh foreach { c => save("meow.txt", c.saveMeow _) }
```

If you're repeatedly doing this, you can abstract it,

```
def currentSaveMeow(file: String) = currentKitteh foreach { c =>
  save(file, c.saveMeow _)
}
currentSaveMeow("meow.txt")
```

I suppose to answer your original question, you could also push the logic into the function argument,

```
save("meow.txt", file => currentKitten.foreach(_.saveMeow(file)))
```

The semantics are a little different with this version.

*Update*. If `k: Option[Kitteh]` is replaced by `k: Either[Throwable, Kitteh]`, then what about `k.right foreach { c => ... }`? You could also use `k.right map ...` if you want to preserve error information.

---

In response to the modified question, here's another abstraction possibility,

```
def save(filename: String, f: (Kitteh, File) => Unit)
```

Now `save` has the responsibility of unpacking `currentKitteh`. Call `save` like this,

```
save("meow.txt", (k, f) => k.saveMeow(f))
```

or like this,

```
save("meow.txt", _ saveMeow _)
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem is that if `currentKitteh` is `None` then the `save` method doesn't get called at all. I didn't specify it properly above, but the `save` method includes a check on whether `currentKitteh` is defined and shows the user a warning if it's not. This is part of the shared functionality that I want to avoid duplicating. In the `foreach` solution we are effectively doing the `isDefined` check in-place. But there might not be anything better!

Comment: The `save("meow.txt", file => currentKitten.foreach(_.saveMeow(file)))
` version does indeed work! Now I'll take a look at your other idea...

Comment: Your second abstraction possibility works too. Nice one! Just to make sure I understand your comment above, which version are you recommending?

Comment: << *unclear comment above deleted* >> I personally like the last version: since `save` has already unpacked `currentKitteh`, it makes sense not to duplicate that logic at the call-site.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a function to it and getOrElse your fail function:

```
def save = 
  o map {s => () => "saved a kitteh! " + s} getOrElse {() => "oh noes, no kittehs!"}
```

then you just:

```
save()
```

Comment: Nice try, but this doesn't allow me to specify the method to be called on the Kitteh at the call site

Comment: How do you mean? You are just mapping functions… You can map them anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class BadKitteh and have that produce error messages. Then simply use currentKitty.getOrElse(badKitty) if you need one.